# String Copy in C

Tags: c, string, malloc, strcpy, strdup

I have a function which I pass a character pointer to, like:

```
funtion_name (char* string){
...
}
```

I want to copy the string to a temporary string variable, then copy that into a struct. This is what I have done thus far:

```
char* namecpy = malloc(strlen(string+1));
strcpy(namecpy, string);
strcpy(ptr->name, namecpy);
```

This is giving me a segmentation fault when I call the function. I think it's because I'm not allowed to directly copy into the struct variable... but how else would I have to copy it?

Comment: Strlen(string) + 1

Answer (score 1):

You're copying it twice and presumably the second target, `ptr->name` isn't allocated properly so it crashes.

What you mean to do is this:

```
ptr->name = malloc(strlen(string)+1);
strcpy(ptr->name, string);
```

Allocate the buffer *at* the target location. Don't mess around with temporary variables unless you absolutely have to.

*Every* buffer you write to must have sufficient memory allocated to it *in advance*. C isn't going to check this for you, it will do exactly what you ask without hesitation, so like when operating a dangerous piece of equipment like a chainsaw you must pay very close attention to how you're using it.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the malloc and strcpy together with the `strdup` function.  (`#include <string.h>`)

```
ptr->name = strdup(string);
```

don't forget to call `free` on ptr->name after you are done with it.

Comment: @Deduplicator `strdup()` conforms to SVr4, 4.3BSD, POSIX.1-2001.